# Which estimator is better here?

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, parameter-estimation, mean-square-error

Let $X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_n$ be a random sample from a population with pmf
$$P_\theta(X=x)=\theta^x(1-\theta)^{1-x}, \quad x=0,1; \qquad 0 \leq \theta \leq \frac{1}{2}$$
Compare the method of moment estimator (MME) and the maximun likelihood estimator (MLE), which one is preferred?

Since $E(X)=\theta$, so $\hat{\theta}_\text{MME}=\bar{X}$ anyway (what if $\bar{X} > \frac{1}{2}$?).

And by writing out the likelihood function and taking derivative I got
$$\hat{\theta}_\text{MLE}=\begin{cases}\bar{X} & \text{ if }0\leq \bar{X} \leq \frac{1}{2}\\ \frac{1}{2} & \text{ if } \bar{X}>\frac{1}{2}\end{cases}$$
It seems the MLE is better, but is there a justification here?

Comment: If it matters in a "better" sense, your MLE is biased, while your MME  is not.  But your MLE will never be further from the actual $\theta$ than your MME is, which might also be seen as "better"

Comment: A known pathology of method-of-moments estimators is that they can lie outside the parameter space and even outside the convex hull of the parameter space. Sometimes they yield negative numbers as estimates of variances. The MLE clearly has a uniformly smaller mean squared error in this case, and sometimes estimators are judged accordingly. MLEs, on the other hand are always within the closure of the parameter space.

Comment: @Henry : Unbiasedness is overrated, and sometimes is a very bad thing. All statisticians know that, but it seems many others do not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is quite possible that observed value of the sample mean $\overline X(=\hat\theta_{\text{MME}})$ does not satisfy the constraint $\theta\in[0,1/2]$. So in those cases, $\overline X$ will not be an entirely appropriate estimator of $\theta$.

But as you rightly obtained, $\hat\theta_{\text{MLE}}=\overline XI_{0\le \overline X\le \frac12}+\frac12I_{\overline X>\frac12}$. So the constraint $\theta\in[0,1/2]$ is well taken care of. In general, MLE is always 'better' in the sense that you obtain the estimator directly based on given data. Besides, it has other appealing optimal properties.

Formally, it can be shown here that MLE is better than MME in terms of mean square error (MSE):

For $\theta\in[0,\frac12]$,

\begin{align}
\operatorname{MSE}_{\theta}(\hat\theta_{\text{MLE}})&=\mathbb E_{\theta}(\hat\theta_{\text{MLE}}-\theta)^2
\\&=\sum_{0\le j\le \frac12}(j-\theta)^2\mathbb P_{\theta}(\overline X=j)+\sum_{j>\frac12}\left(\frac12-\theta\right)^2\mathbb P_{\theta}(\overline X=j)
\end{align}

And

\begin{align}
\operatorname{MSE}_{\theta}(\hat\theta_{\text{MME}})&=\mathbb E_{\theta}(\overline X-\theta)^2
\\&=\sum_{0\le j\le \frac12}(j-\theta)^2\mathbb P_{\theta}(\overline X=j)+\sum_{j>\frac12}(j-\theta)^2\mathbb P_{\theta}(\overline X=j)
\end{align}

So for every $\theta\in[0,\frac12]$,

\begin{align}
\operatorname{MSE}_{\theta}(\hat\theta_{\text{MLE}})-\operatorname{MSE}_{\theta}(\hat\theta_{\text{MME}})&=\sum_{j>\frac12}\left[\left(\frac12-\theta\right)^2-(j-\theta)^2\right]\mathbb P_{\theta}(\overline X=j)
\end{align}

Since $\left(\frac12-\theta\right)^2-(j-\theta)^2=\left(\frac12+j-2\theta\right)\left(\frac12-j\right)<0$ for $j>\frac12$ and $\theta\in[0,\frac12]$,

$$\operatorname{MSE}_{\theta}(\hat\theta_{\text{MLE}})<\operatorname{MSE}_{\theta}(\hat\theta_{\text{MME}})\quad,\forall\,\theta\in\left[0,\frac12\right]$$

Comment: Thanks. So in other cases, we usually compare the bias or the variance to decide which estimator is better. However, I am not sure how to formally justify that MLE is better than MME here...

Comment: @Nan As long as the comparison is with the method of moments estimator, I would simply say that the MLE is *most likely* to explain your observed data. Your choice of criteria in choosing estimators would depend on the purpose of estimation. But sure, you may compare the bias, variance, mse etc.